# Why is doParallel R performing worse in this case?

Tags: r, parallel-processing

Can someone explain why parLapply is the slowest?

```
> cl <- makeCluster(no_cores)
> myVar<-2:4000
> microbenchmark(
+ Reduce("+",parLapply(cl,myVar,function(X) X^2)),
+ Reduce("+",lapply(myVar,function(X) X^2)),
+ Reduce("+",myVar^2)
+ )
Unit: milliseconds
                                               expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq       max neval
 Reduce("+", parLapply(cl, myVar, function(X) X^2)) 6.988662 8.041860 9.061966 8.901447 9.916621 14.541828   100
        Reduce("+", lapply(myVar, function(X) X^2)) 5.256892 5.626853 6.892995 6.259239 8.165724 11.112812   100
                               Reduce("+", myVar^2) 1.930513 2.137887 2.613923 2.279481 3.000740  6.194623   100
```

**Based on the comments I added a sum implementation and a vectorized implementation:**

```
> vec_exp<-Vectorize(function(x)x^2)
> cl <- makeCluster(no_cores)
> myVar<-2:4000
> microbenchmark(
+ Reduce("+",parLapply(cl,myVar,function(X) X^2)),
+ Reduce("+",lapply(myVar,function(X) X^2)),
+ Reduce("+",myVar^2),
+ sum(myVar^2),
+ Reduce("+",vec_exp(myVar))
+ )
Unit: microseconds
                                               expr      min       lq       mean   median       uq       max neval
 Reduce("+", parLapply(cl, myVar, function(X) X^2)) 6880.426 7086.400 7589.02901 7253.886 7625.246 12055.674   100
        Reduce("+", lapply(myVar, function(X) X^2)) 5073.078 5356.030 5826.33276 5478.029 5728.324  8472.236   100
                               Reduce("+", myVar^2) 1922.582 1998.861 2174.07136 2041.548 2129.023  4427.864   100
                                       sum(myVar^2)   13.530   17.495   19.65554   18.662   20.528    34.990   100
                        Reduce("+", vec_exp(myVar)) 5686.102 5967.655 6632.46879 6210.952 6671.186 16191.488   100
```

Comment: Parallelization makes only sense if the operation to parallelize is significantly more expensive than copying data. x^2 is more or less the same cost like copying x - that's not an appropriate use case for parallelization. You are just generating much overhead.

Comment: As this is highly verctorizable compare the timing with `sum(myVar^2)`. See also @user2589273 answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For more processors [Amdahls law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law) starts to kick in. However for your case, the latency of setting up the parallel system (even with no cores? shouldn't it be 1) plays a significant role in your problem.

It often takes a significant time to produce a cluster, regardless of size, which makes simple calculations less efficient to parallelise. It is often better to [vectorise](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Vectorize.html) them if possible and use the underlying hardware to your full advantage.

Additionally the call to the parallel lapply function requires it to setup all the message passing routines, split the data (into 1 in your case), and get ready to receive it once calculated. This presents the delay which you are experiencing.

The serial lapply on the other hand just begins its calculations, not worring about any of the above. Since the calculations are pretty simple, it tends to finish a lot sooner. (ie. It doesn't need to faff around with any of the setting up parLapply has to do.)

I suggest comparing a 2+ core parallel scenario. Here you should see that for simple/quick calculations it is better to keep the program serial, and with more complicated ones, it helps to distribute the work (if possible).

Comment: I took a look the 'Vectorize' documentation, and tried to include an implementation above but I am uncertain when to use it in general. Can you explain more about when you should use `Vectorize` rather than parallel or just non-parallel implementations?